# Use Powershell to compare two xml documents and print difference which include parent path

Tags: xml, powershell, path, location, compare

I'd like to find a way in **Powershell** to compare two xml documents, where the script will print the *'difference items'* and include parent path for each difference.

I have two XML files that I'd like to compare.

**File A (XML):**

```
<products>
  <product name="demo">
    <addresslist type="IPv4">
      <address>8.8.8.8</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="URL">
      <address>boom.com</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>
</products>
```

**File B (XML**, where **`<address>4.4.4.4</address>`** is the difference):

```
<products>
  <product name="demo">
    <addresslist type="IPv4">
      <address>8.8.8.8</address>
      <address>4.4.4.4</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="URL">
      <address>boom.com</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>
</products>
```

My Powershell script is this:

```
$A_xml = ("A-file.xml")

$B_xml = ("B-file.xml")

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $A_xml) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $B_xml)
```

Unfortunately, the result is:

```
<address>4.4.4.4</address>         <=
```

What I'd like the result to be:

```
<products>
  <product name="demo">
    <addresslist type="IPv4">
      <address>4.4.4.4</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>
</products>
```

Which would include the parent path for the diff item(s).

Comment: What if 3.3.3.3 was in A?  Would think you assume A is the answer, if a node in A is in B, remove from A & B.  Add all remaining in B to A.  Scrub empty nodes maybe.  Done.  At least that is the top of mind approach.

Comment: File A would be a source.  File B would be a newly updated file, so any difference would be at B, and removal or additions would be showed as => or <= (I think, sorry hadn't even thought about a => option)

Comment: You'll have to write a recursive function like [this one](https://gist.github.com/ctigeek/3726bb02055d0558fdd9cd3ffb292dbf) but instead of `throw` you'll output the difference.